# Green lines are invisible in diff output for some files in *shell*

Tags: shell, colors, text

I use Emacs a lot including for most terminal sessions. One of activities includes typing git commands inside a shell buffer.

I found a very interesting color puzzle.
After downloading forked repository https://github.com/yaitskov/java-nio-tcp-proxy 
I encountered that new lines which should be green are blank.
And only deleted lines are visible (in red color).
It was a big surprise for me because I did it a lot of times with different repositories.

After trying different combinations there are facts:

`git diff --color` works well in other existing and new GIT repositories
in Emacs shell, Emacs term, Emacs ansi-term and gnome-terminal.

`git diff --color` works well for any GIT repo in
Emacs term, Emacs ansi-term and gnome-terminal.

Not all files in the repo have the bug. But most of them do (java files, `pom.xml`).

But green lines are visible for `config.properties`.

I aware that a shell buffer is not 100% terminal. 
But I'm thrilled by this instability.

Comment: Try changing the color theme.

Comment: I believe this is the same problem as https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73596/emacs-shell-git-diff-not-displaying-inserted-lines-with-dos-file-endings/76265#76265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it only happens on files with DOS line endings. The carriage return at the end is apparently messing with the rendering of those lines in shell-mode.