# Emacs shell - git diff not displaying inserted ("+") lines with dos file endings and color

Tags: shell, eshell, line-endings

If I modify a file checked into version control with DOS line endings, on a normal terminal I can see the change:

```
# Normal terminal...
$ git diff
diff --git a/a b/a
index c113281..85c3ecd 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 Line 1
-Line 2
+Line two^M
 Line 3
```

However, in emacs shell (`M-x shell`) I can only see the `-` line - the `+` line appears to have disappeared, presumably because it's interpreting the `^M` at the end as "go back to the start of the line (erasing any characters on it)":

```
# Emacs shell...
$ git diff
diff --git a/a b/a
index c113281..85c3ecd 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 Line 1
-Line 2

 Line 3
```

This only happens if it's displaying colors, though I've no idea why that would be. It happens even if I start emacs with `--no-init`, so I'm sure it's not just some weird setting in my config.

Any ideas on how to fix this? (I can work around with `--color=never` but I'd rather have an actual fix)

(To create the above example I made a file with `set-buffer-file-coding-system` set to `dos`)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `comint-inhibit-carriage-motion` to `t`